# How To get Selected Column From Database to JTable in Java

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable

I Have Made a Pogram Where I have To Store Selected Column From Database into `JTable` and I Also Have to store some data from `JTextField` into same `JTable` I have tried lots of things but it is not getting the right result it shows error like `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:0` the source code is too long to paste enough but i pasted some useful line which getting you to understand my problem.

The database has some column like:

```
/*** ProductInfo Table******//
CREATE TABLE ProductInfo (
P_Code VARCHAR (45) PRIMARY KEY
NOT NULL,
P_Name VARCHAR (45),
Category VARCHAR (45),
SubCategory VARCHAR (45) ,
Description VARCHAR (500),
Cost_Price VARCHAR (45),
Selling_Price VARCHAR (45),
Reorder_Point INTEGER (10),
Opening_Stock INTEGER (10),
Discount INTEGER (10),
VAT INTEGER (10),
P_Image BLOB,
}
```

And This is the `JTable` where i have to store the information

```
/*** StockInfo Table******//
CREATE TABLE StockInfo (
P_Code VARCHAR (45) ,
P_Name VARCHAR (45),
Description VARCHAR (500),
Selling_Price VARCHAR (45),
Opening_Stock INTEGER (10),
Discount INTEGER (10),
VAT INTEGER (10),
Date Date,
Pay_Due Varchar(45),
Tot_Pay varchar(45),
}

  public void InsertDataToStockInfo()
{
    try
    {
        ProductList obj=new ProductList(); //it is that JTable from where i have to fetch some column.
        model=(DefaultTableModel)obj.table.getModel();
        for(int i=0;i<obj.table.getColumnCount();i++)
        {
            String P_Code=model.getValueAt(i,0).toString();
            String P_Name=model.getValueAt(i,1).toString();
            String Description=model.getValueAt(i,4).toString();
            String Selling_Price=model.getValueAt(i,6).toString();
            String qnty=model.getValueAt(i, 8).toString();
            int Qnty=Integer.parseInt(qnty);
            String discount=model.getValueAt(i,9).toString();
            int Discount=Integer.parseInt(discount);
            String vAT=model.getValueAt(i,10).toString();
            int VAT=Integer.parseInt(vAT);

            query="Insert into StockInfo (P_Code,P_Name,Description,Selling_Price,Qnty,Discount,VAT)"
                    + "Select P_Code,P_Name,Description,Selling_Price,Opening_Stock,Discount,VAT from ProductInfo where P_Code='"+P_Code+"'";
            PStat=con.prepareStatement(query);

            PStat.setString(1,P_Code);
            PStat.setString(2,P_Name);
            PStat.setString(3,Description);
            PStat.setString(4,Selling_Price);
            PStat.setInt(5,Qnty);
            PStat.setInt(6,Discount);
            PStat.setInt(7,VAT);

            // here i also want to add some more information from JTextfield into the columns in JTable is it possible.

            PStat.addBatch();
        }
        PStat.executeBatch();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Data Saved from ProductInfo");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
    }
    finally
    {
    try
    {
    PStat.close();
    res.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: 1) Please use an upper case letter at the start of sentences, for the word I, and proper names like `ArrayList` or Oracle. But **leave it at that.** Starting every other word with upper case letters does not make the message more clear, and instead makes me want to close the question and help someone else. 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: `i` is iterating over the column indices of the table model, but you're using it as the row-index argument when calling `getValueAt()`.  Maybe you meant to write `i<obj.table.getRowCount()` for your loop limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have to take datas from DB, it will give you columns number / columns names and concrete datas

```
public DefaultTableModel CreateTableModel(){
  //--

     String query = "select field1,field2...";
     ResultSet results = statment.executeQuery(query);

//--
 }
```

now create a method to take columns_name or just naming it by yourself and add this to the model

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
String[] ColumnNamesCollections = GetColumnsNameByQuery(query);
model.setColumnIdentifiers(ColumnNamesCollections);
```

now just iterate your result set and fill you table

```
while(results.next())
{
   Vector<Objetc> element = new Vector<Object>

   for(counter=0;counter<ColumnNamesCollections.size();counter++)
   {

      element.add(results.getObjetc(counter))
   }

   model.addRow(element);
}
```

---

```
DefaultTableModel model = CreateTableModel();
java.swing.JTable myTable = new java.swing.JTable(model)
```